# Optimization when Shuffle write is large and spark task become super slow

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

There's a SparkSQL which will join 4 large tables (50 million for first 3 table and 200 million for the last table) and do some group by operation which consumes 60 days of data. and this SQL will take 2 hours to run, during which time, I checked that `Shuffle Write` is increasing dramatically which could go up to more than 200GB.

For contrast, when I decrease the consuming date range from 60 days to 45 days, it only takes 6.3min to run. I checked at the DAG graph, for 45 days of data, it outputs 1 billion data after the last sortMergeJoin.

Could anyone give me some idea which direction could I optimize this scenario? Thanks!

**P.S.**

possible related info:

- Spark.version=2.1.0
- spark.executor.instances=20
- spark.executor.memory=6g
- spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=5g

Answer (score 1):

You need to partition data to parallelize jobs properly make sure in Spark UI partition are distributed data properly .

The default implementation of a join in Spark is a shuffled hash join. The shuffled hash join ensures that data on each partition will contain the same keys by partitioning the second dataset with the same default partitioner as the first, so that the keys with the same hash value from both datasets are in the same partition. While this approach always works, it can be more expensive than necessary because it requires a shuffle. The shuffle can be avoided if:

- Both RDDs have a known partitioner.
- One of the datasets is small enough to fit in memory, in which case we can do a broadcast hash join

The easiest optimization is that if one of the datasets is small enough to fit in memory, it should be broadcasted to every compute node. This use case is very common as data needs to be combined with side data, such as a dictionary, all the time.

Mostly joins are slow due to too much data being shuffled over the network. With the Broadcast join, the smaller dataset is copied to all the worker nodes so the original parallelism of the larger DataFrame is maintained.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html

Comment: hey man, thanks for the detailed answer. Actually, there's partition in all the first 3 tables (50 million in size for 60 days partitions) and no partition support for the last one table (200 million in size for 60 days). and there are small tables, which i could see from DAG graph, that they are `BroadCastJoin` as expected. However, there are multiple (6/7) `SortMergeJoin` on these big tables during comuting. That's the phenomenon. Any more suggestions?

Comment: What kind of partition are you using ?

Comment: partitioned on `day=yyyy-MM-dd`, so I only retrieve the last 60 days data, which is 50 million in size totally

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html                                         
 plz check if you are using groupBy key so avoid reduceBKey etc and other performance tips

Comment: I'm writing SparkSQL, so it should optimize this one by default.

Comment: What is "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" value you have added ?

Comment: I checked under Environment and this key is not set, so i think it remains default 200

Comment: Can you try this  ./bin/spark-submit --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=300 --conf spark.default.parallelism=300